# Method for testing database connectivity with Firebase Realtime Database JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If there is not - is there a problem with trying to fetch a ref to a database key that a user doesn't have access to, and checking whether we get a server response denying access?

Is a denied request still a billable event? If it's not, then I think that checking whether we get a rejection or a timeout seems like an alright method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test whether the client can connect to the database by listening to the `.info/connected` node. For more info, see [detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

There is no way to perform a separate test whether the user has read access to a node. You will have to try and read the node, and handle the result. If you're worried about the size of the node, you can request the path using the REST API and pass `shallow=true` to only get a minimal result.

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't charge for disk reads. So if a read is rejected, the JSON data is not returned to the client, and you won't be charged for bandwidth of that JSON.